# ARcore support Depth API devices

Tags: android, augmented-reality

heloo everyone  i have some question about  arcore suport device table, if the devices don't have comments suport depth API is that mean the device not suport for depth API?.
but when i see the iphone table that no coment suport for depth api.
thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6WRI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOAkT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, only the devices commented with "Support Depth API" will support it. iPhones won't support ArCore Depth API functionality, but selected devices can support Depth using ARKit, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/arkit/).